how can i send the checked row to the first at datatables
This code actually works adding row, however when i checked the primary contact it didnt send to the first row instead it send to the last, kindly help me to fix this.
  //add row in contact
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var table = $('#lv_Lead_Contact_Information-datatable').DataTable({
          dom: "t"
      });

      //ensure the primary contract is only one
      $(document).on('change', '.primary-contact-checkbox', function () {
          if (this.checked) {
              // Uncheck all other checkboxes
              $('.primary-contact-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);

              // Get the row of the checked checkbox
              var row = $(this).closest('tr');

              // Move the row to the top of the table
              row.fadeOut(function () {
                  table.row(row).remove().draw(false);
                  table.row.add(row[0]).draw(false);
                  row.fadeIn();
              });
          }
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#btnAddContact', function () {
          table.row.add([
              '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input primary-contact-checkbox" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 21px;">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">',
              '<input type="checkbox" class="" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 19px;">',
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-borderless">'
          ]).draw();
      });
  });


unable to understand your question fully, could you please elaborate a bit more? what you are trying to achieve is not clear

my goal in the table, when the field checkbox is checked in the row then the row must send to the first row of the table

See row.add (datatables) : "The rows that are added are subjected to the ordering and search criteria that are applied to the table, which will determine the new row's position and visibility in the table."  In other words, you can't specify where the row will appear when it's the same data as all the other rows.   What you should be doing is sorting on the first column's tickbox value, then there's no need for remove/add, it will move automatically on .draw()

I think what you are looking for is when you select a primary contact row, that row should automatically move to the first row of the table.
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#lv_Lead_Contact_Information-datatable').on('click', '.primary-contact-checkbox', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); // Get the row containing the clicked checkbox
    var $tbody = $row.closest('tbody'); // Get the table body

    // Remove the row from its current position and insert it at the top
    $row.remove().prependTo($tbody);
});

});

it will not work with pagination.once you will come back from other page to first page it will go to initial position

Or even just redraw the datatable.  Don't manipulate the DOM when using datatables - make changes to datatable's data and redraw.

... then add a table.draw() after the .prepend

@Bubbles  it will not work for data tables with paginations bro. also you will loose search over newly added rows

This wont work for pagination and @Bubbles you have to save the data so that next time when the table loads it loads the primary contact first

guys, I see your point but in my case where  dom: "t" and I already disable sorting.
